# Java: Missing libraries

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a bit new to Java / Processing and I opened up a project/workspace with the following errors:

```
is missing required library: '/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/javamail/smtp.jar' 
/javamail/dsn.jar
/javamail/mailapi.jar
/javamail/pop3.jar
```

I have the Processing app installed, but it's been a while...do I just need to upgrade processing or is there another place I need to go to get these .jar files?

I'm using Eclipse and there seems to be quite a list of referenced jar files (some broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that there used to be a library at

```
/Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/javamail/smtp.jar
```

but it's no longer there, or possibly you opened a project that somebody else edited on a different machine where things were laid out differently.

Open the project build-path dialog and make sure all the libraries point to the correct locations.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem still persist, try doing clean and build in eclipse. It might help.